# Using LocalDate in Spring context and avoid CGLib issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a small job written with Spring Boot Batch 2.2.2. It takes a date as a parameter, and since several components need that date, I place it as a bean in the Spring context :

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public Date processingDate(){
if(isEmpty(applicationArguments.getSourceArgs())){
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("No parameter received - expecting a date to be passed as a command line parameter.");
}

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(EXPECTED_DATE_FORMAT);
String expectedDateFromCommandLine=applicationArguments.getSourceArgs()[0];

try {

  return sdf.parse(expectedDateFromCommandLine);

} catch (ParseException e) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expecting the parameter date to have this format : "+ EXPECTED_DATE_FORMAT,e);
}
}
```

It works well, no issue.

Now I am doing some refactoring, and thought I should use LocalDate instead of Date, as it is now recommended since Java 8.

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public LocalDate processingDate(){

    if(isEmpty(applicationArguments.getSourceArgs())){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No parameter received - expecting a date to be passed as a command line parameter.");
    }

    String expectedDateFromCommandLine=applicationArguments.getSourceArgs()[0];

    return LocalDate.parse(expectedDateFromCommandLine, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(EXPECTED_DATE_FORMAT));

}
```

However, Spring doesn't like it :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class java.time.LocalDate: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class java.time.LocalDate
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:208)
```

I understand that behind the scene, Spring does some magic with some proxy-ing and all.. But there must be an easy way to make this possible, right ?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19159472/spring-batch-stepscope-cannot-generate-cglib-subclass ?

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate - the link you mention has a fix for XML config. But I am not using XML config, and it says clearly there that another question should be asked in that case. Thanks for poiting it out though - I didn't think it could come from the StepScope annotation, but now I guess it is a good lead

Comment: Is your application just the batch job? If yes, does the date really need to be in stepscope? Maybe just making a simple bean would solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Javadoc of [StepScope](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/StepScope.html):

```
Marking a @Bean as @StepScope is equivalent to marking it as @Scope(value="step", proxyMode=TARGET_CLASS)
```

Now the proxy mode `TARGET_CLASS` means the proxy will be a CGLIB proxy (See [ScopedProxyMode#TARGET_CLASS](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ScopedProxyMode.html#TARGET_CLASS)) which mean a sub-class of the bean type will be created for the proxy. Since you are declaring a step scoped bean of type `LocalDate` which is a final class, Spring (Batch) is unable to create the proxy, hence the error.

I don't see the added value of having a step scoped `LocalDate` bean. A step scoped bean is useful for late binding of job parameters or attributes from the step/job execution context. But if you really want that bean to be step scoped, you can try another proxy mode like:

```
@Scope(value = "step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.DEFAULT)
```

Comment: Thanks - you're right, by refactoring my Spring config, I realized I didn't need it, so I removed it. But for what it's worth, your tip worked ;-)